# create a WIKI like "diff" between two strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parsing, data-visualization, word-diff

i am generating a report showing the different between fields before and after.  I have it working but some of the fields are pretty long and the changes are quite subtle.  I want some visualization to highlight what has changed.

Similar to what you see in:

1. Stackoverflow if you look at question edits
2. One of the text file diff tools when you compare checked in code with older versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This one](http://www.rohland.co.za/index.php/2009/10/31/csharp-html-diff-algorithm/) has worked pretty well for me in my projects.

Comment: i dont have HTML differences (just raw text).  should that matter ?

Comment: @ooo: That's how I've used it as well.  It outputs in HTML with its own styling and such (but you have the code, so you can configure all that), that's how it does its highlighting, but I've been able to just feed it plain strings.